# Certain podcasts not syncing to iPhone when subscribed through iTunes

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization, iphone, podcasts

I subscribe to a lot of podcast both audio and video on iTunes.  I rarely have an issue with the audio but the video ones sometimes will not sync certain podcasts.

For example current the "Fast Lane Daily" video podcast will not sync at all.  I have been watching this podcast for over 2 years but all of sudden it will not sync.

http://itunes.apple.com/ca/podcast/fast-lane-daily-car-news./id217735843

Any ideas what the issue could be?  This seems to happen intermitently with other video podcasts from time to time as well.  Such as the UFC video podcast:

http://itunes.apple.com/ca/podcast/the-best-of-the-ufc/id424338078

It's hit and miss with this one.  Some sync some do not.

Is there a way to identify which ones will not sync even?  Currently this is a manual process after a sync where I go through each podcast and manually verify that they have copied over and identify which ones have not so I can delete those specific 'episodes'.

Is there something I can adjust on my side to ensure the podcasts do sync or is there a way for iTunes to not download ones that will not sync?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an iPhone 3GS? It's possible that the creators of the video podcast changed their video format to high definition. If that is the case,  these items will not sync because the 3GS can't playback certain HD video formats that are targeted for other more powerful Apple devices like iPad or Apple TV.

More info on supported video formats: http://www.macxdvd.com/mac-dvd-video-converter-how-to/iphone-video-format-supported.htm